# Having issues with bar chart x axis labels overlapping and spacing

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I need to essentially do a graph of x-axis (the date) and y-axis (volume sold) and have each day in a calendar year be represented.

[image: Current Graph]

Issues - first is the white space between dates. I tried to use factor(Date), but ran into issues when I wanted additional changes to the graph. The other issue, is the x-axis is currently by month. This looks fine. However, when I try to do it by day, I get ...

[image: Daily]

In short, it looks like a mess. Probably because I'm trying to put every date in at once. Below is my code as is.

```
ggplot(MyDataCSV, aes(x = Date, y = Volume)) +
  geom_col(stat = "identity",
           width = 0.9, 
           fill = "coral",
           alpha = 0.5,
           colour = "black",
           position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", labels = date_format("%m/%d")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  ggtitle("Volume Sold by Date") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I'm a beginner to R, so I know this is beginner level, but I'm very confused. I have ggplot, tidyverse, dplyr, lubridate, and scales installed. Essentially, I want my labels on the x-axis to look like the first picture, except with every date in my data set (about a year)

Comment: I don't understand. If you label every date you'll never be able to read them. You have way too many dates to make that legible. Do you want like a tiny 2pt font or something? When you have that many values, generally you just label a few and let people judge by eye where other values live.

Comment: Do you know how to split it into multiple images? I'd be open to partitioning with a new graph every 2-3 months or something. This is just what I've been asked to do. So that's why I need help. But I realize the legible issue

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to specify the dimensions of the saved figure, e.g.

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Generate a fake dataset (minimal reproducible example)
df <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(from = ymd("2021-01-01"),
                                 to = ymd("2021-12-31"),
                                 by = "1 day"),
                 Volume = runif(365, 0, 4e+08))

# Plot the fake data
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = Volume)) +
  geom_col(stat = "identity",
           width = 0.9, 
           fill = "coral",
           alpha = 0.5,
           colour = "black",
           position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", labels = scales::date_format("%m/%d")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  ggtitle("Volume Sold by Date") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

# Save the plot
ggsave(filename = "example_1.png", width = 60, height = 10, limitsize = FALSE)
```

[image: example_1.png]

Then, if you zoom in, you can see the dates don't overlap:

[image: example_2.png]

Otherwise, you could change the date_breaks to "1 month", or "1 week" to stop the dates overlapping whilst keeping a 'normal' figure size:

```
# Plot the fake data
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = Volume)) +
  geom_col(stat = "identity",
           width = 0.9, 
           fill = "coral",
           alpha = 0.5,
           colour = "black",
           position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", labels = scales::date_format("%m/%d")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  ggtitle("Volume Sold by Date") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image: example_3.png]

Or, the option that I would probably recommend, you could create facets by e.g. every 3 months:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Generate a fake dataset (minimal reproducible example)
df <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(from = ymd("2021-01-01"),
                                 to = ymd("2021-12-31"),
                                 by = "1 day"),
                 Volume = runif(365, 0, 4e+08))

plot_labels <- c(
  "1" = "First Quarter, 2021",
  "2" = "Second Quarter, 2021",
  "3" = "Third Quarter, 2021",
  "4" = "Fourth Quarter, 2021"
)
# Plot the fake data
df %>%
  mutate(quarter = cut.Date(Date, breaks = "quarter", labels = FALSE)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = Date, y = Volume)) +
  geom_col(stat = "identity",
           width = 0.9, 
           fill = "coral",
           alpha = 0.5,
           colour = "black",
           position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", labels = scales::date_format("%m/%d")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  ggtitle("Volume Sold by Date") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  facet_wrap(~ quarter, ncol = 1, scales = "free_x",
             labeller = labeller(quarter = plot_labels))
```

[image: example_4.png]

Comment: Thank you for this. Out of curiosity, is there any other way to make the date labels fit that doesn't involve the adjustments when you save? Like, is there any way to alter the width of the image otherwise? Also, is there anything we can do about spaces like using factor?

Comment: When you say "is there any way to alter the width of the image otherwise?", do you mean in the R/RStudio viewer window? You can click and drag the window to make it larger in RStudio; is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Well, I mean, when I exported the image with your save and size specifications, it worked. Without it, I get that jumbled mess - even if I zoom in. I'm mostly wondering if we can get it to spit it out with the correct sizing without having to explicitly save the file at the end I guess.

Comment: The answer is "yes you can", but it is more complicated. You would need to resize each component of the plot using `theme()`. If you are able to post your actual data it would make it easier to evaluate whether or not it's a viable solution (e.g. edit your post to include the output from `dput(MyDataCSV)`)